# Select destination variable for click parser

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, python-click

I'm wondering how to override destination variable for the `click.option` ([Click lib](http://click.pocoo.org/6/)). For example in such piece of code

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--output', default='data')
def generate_data(output_folder):
    print(output_folder)
```

So I want to use `--output` flag but pass its value to `output_folder` argument, kinda this: `@click.option('--output', default='data', dest='output_folder')`?
Is there is such an ability in click? I know that argparse allow such a behaviour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, see the section in the click documentation on [parameter names](http://click.pocoo.org/5/parameters/#parameter-names), which covers both options and arguments.

> If a parameter is not given a name without dashes, a name is generated automatically by taking the longest argument and converting all dashes to underscores. For an option with `('-f', '--foo-bar')`, the parameter name is `foo_bar`. For an option with `('-x',)`, the parameter is `x`. ***For an option with `('-f', '--filename', 'dest')`, the parameter is called `dest`.***

Here's your example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--output', 'data')
def generate_data(data):
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_data()
```

Running it:

```
$ python2.7 stack_overflow.py --output some_output
some_output
```

Comment: Keep in mind that for Arguments this won't work, and instead throws an Exception: `TypeError: Arguments take exactly one parameter declaration, got 2.`